# Intersection of 2 sets of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do you find the intersection of these two sub-spaces of (the set of real numbers)^3?

$S=\{  a(0, -1, 1)^T + b(-2, 0, 0)^T \}$, $T=\{  c(1, -3, 1)^T + d(0, 2, 2)^T \}$?

I set the general vectors equal to each other and get:

$-2b=c$,

$-a=-3c+2d$,

$a=c+2d$

From this, I don't see how to obtain the intersection.

Note: a,b,c and d are real numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't the $4$ in your last equation be a $2$?

Comment: Assuming your equations are right, from (2) and (3) we get that $c=2d$. With that and the first relation (1), we can conclude $a = 4d$, $b=-d$ and $c = 2d$. The intersection can be described by $d\begin{pmatrix}  4 \\ -1 \\ 2 \\1\end{pmatrix}$ where $d$ is some constant.

Comment: yes it should, thanks, I will see if this makes a difference.

Comment: @felasta I dont agree, the solution should be in $\mathbb{R}^3.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First method:**

You have a system of 3 equations with 4 unknowns.

Solve it by keeping the 3 (arbitrary) "main" variables $a,b,c$ only in the LHS and considering $d$ as parameter and obtain:

$$\pmatrix{a\\b\\c}=\pmatrix{4d\\-d \\2d }$$

It suffices to use the expressions of $a$ and $b$ to obtain:

$$S=\{  4d(0, -1, 1)^T + -d(-2, 0, 0)^T = d(2 ,  -4, 4)^T\}.$$

Thus the intersecting line passes through the origin with directing vector $(2 ,  -4, 4)^T $ or any non zero vector proportional to it like $(1,-2,2)^T$...

**Second method:**

Let $U,V$ be the cross products :

$$U=(0, -1, 1)^T \times (-2, 0, 0)^T \ \ \ V=(1, -3, 1)^T \times (0, 2, 2)^T.$$

$U,V$ are normal vectors to the planes under consideration. Thus their intersecting has $U \times V=(8,16,-16)$ for a directing vector. This vector is in fact proportional to the one we just have found by the first method.

Comment: I am going to give as well a different method.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a mistake in your third equation; the system should be:

$$-2b=c$$
$$-a=-3c+2d$$
$$a=c+2d$$

Adding the last two:

$$0=-2c+4d\implies 0=-c+2d\implies c=2d$$

and, from the first equation, $b=-d$. Can you take it from here?

Also, here's another approach: Find vectors $v$ and $w$ orthogonal to $S$ and $T$, respectively, and note that $v\times w$ generates the intersection (the intersection of two distinct planes through the origin is a line).